# excel chart date displaying in daily instead of weekly

Tags: excel, charts

I have 2 sets of date to display on my excel histogram chart. However the dates which are on the x-axis will tend to display dates in daily sequence - even though i only have data on a weekly basis. How do i remove the dates that are irrelevant here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

1. Hover over the x-axis, right-click, and select **Format Axis**
2. In the dialog box select the **Scale** tab
3. Adjust the **Major Unit** input to 7 days

Comment: excellent solution however the spacing does between the dates does not reduce despite the absence of other dates. any way i could remove spacing in between dates 1 week apart?

Comment: Could you edit your post with a snapshot of your data and maybe even a image of your chart that shows the issue you are having? I am not entirely clear what the problem is but can most likely help if you provide more info...

Answer (score 4):

Change the axis from "Automatic" or "Date" or "Time" to "Text" or "Category" (nomenclature varies with Excel version).

In Excel 2007 or 2010 it's on the main screen of the Format Axis dialog. In Excel 2003 and earlier, you need to go to Chart menu > Chart Options > Axes.

Comment: yep, this was very helpful - Excel 2010 (trying to use weekly dates as horizontal axis) - select axis type "text axis", tick marks > interval between marks set to 1, "labels" > "interval between labels" set to 1 - done!